# Rails4 - The same book can appeared many times in the user page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I need help to fix the following problem:

I have Rails application with `books` where users can add `comments`. For each `comment`, there is a `user.email` and a `user.message` which is displayed. There is an association beetween `user` and `comment` and so when you clicked on the `user.email` which is displayed, it redirects to the `user` page and it displays all the books that the user has read.

But the problem that is : when the same user adds many comments, his user page displays the same book many times whereas he has read it just one time.

For more details, you can test it yourself with my appplication deployed with Heroku : https://library-online-duofer.herokuapp.com
and see the code with : https://github.com/chtrang/Duong_Fernandez

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try doing it like this, `@books = @user.books.pluck(:title, :author).uniq` in `users_controller`.

Comment: @Sahil : Thank you Sahil your answer. i put  books =user.books.pluck(:title, :author).uniq in users_controller , in the method show. But i have the error : '["Harry Potter", "Rowling"]' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Comment: What about `@books = @user.books.distinct`  , would that work?

Comment: Can you show the relationships you have setup for `Book`, `Comment` and `User`. Just show the `has_many` and `belongs_to` portions.